# how to restrict access to a file in .htaccess to a particular domain

Tags: .htaccess

I want to restrict access to a file "test.txt" with .htaccess
The problem, I'm on a multisite and I want only one domain to access to the file eg. mydomain.com/test.txt

When other domain trying to access, it should denied them:  otherdomain.com/test.txt

Multisite is sharing the same files but different db.

```
<Files "test.txt">
  Order deny,allow
  deny from all
  allow from mydomain.com
</Files>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts in your question, could you please do mention sample url which you want to restrict to get better understanding of question, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this deny rewrite rule instead of `allow/deny`:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^test\.txt$ - [NC,F]
```